Solve the inequality $\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2} \ge0$, $x \ne-2,+2$
Solve the inequality $\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2} \ge0$, $x \ne-2,+2$
My Attempt :
$\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2} \ge0 \implies 
|x|-1 \ge0 \implies |x|\ge1$. In this method, my solution set doesn't match with required answer. Secondly, there are two cases arises (1) $\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2} \ge0 \implies 
|x|-1 \ge0$ and $|x|-2 \ge0$
(2)$\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2} \ge0 \implies 
|x|-1 \le0$ and $|x|-2 \le0 \implies x \in (-2,-1) \cup [-1,1] \cup (1,2)$
I couldn't approach the actual answer. Please help me.

$a/b \geq 0$ is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. So you have 2 cases: $a$ and $b$ both negative or $a$ and $b$ both positive. Par exemple $|x|-1 \geq 0$ is equivalent $x\in (-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$. You can do the same for $|x|-2\geq 0$ and take the intersection since $x$ must verify both at the same time.

You can not cross multiply and keep the sign of inequality intact as the denominator is not always positive

@MarcDinh, shouldn't one take the union of both case?

Ah sorry, I wasn't clear, take the intersection of $|x|-1\geq 0$ and $|x|-2\geq 0$ but take the union of the positive and negative cases.

For this inequality to be more than 0, two cases are possible. Either both the numerator and denominator are greater than $0$ (so $|x|>1 ]\text{ and } |x|>2$), so
$|x|>2$.
Alternatively $|x|-1\leq0$, and $|x|-2<0$. so $|x|\leq1$
So take the union of both cases to get your answer

When $x≥ 0$ we have to solve
$$\frac{x-1}{x-2}≥ 0 \label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
whose solution is $x \in (-\infty,1] \cup (2,+\infty)$. With the condition above we got
$$S_1 =  [0,1] \cup (2,+\infty)$$
Similarly goes for $x<0$ we have to solve
$$\frac{-x-1}{-x-2}≥ 0 \label{eq2}\tag{2}$$
whose solution is
$$S_2 = (-\infty,-2)\cup [-1,0)$$
and the final solution is the union so
$$S = S_1 \cup S_2 = (-\infty,-2)\cup [-1,1] \cup (2,+\infty)$$

If $0\not \in S_1$ and $0 \not \in S_2$ how is that $0 \in S_1\cup S_2$?

@jjagmath $0 \in S_1$ I've used a "(" where is meant to be a "[", I've edited it.

Sign table (method) for $f(x)=\frac{|x|-1}{|x|-2}
$
$$\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&-2&&-1&&1&&2\\\hline
|x|-1&+&+&+&0&-&0&+&+&+\\\hline
|x|-2&+&0&-&-&-&-&-&0&+\\\hline
f(x)&+&\pm\infty&-&0&+&0&-&\pm\infty&+\\\hline
\end{array}$$
$S=\{x|f(x)\geq0\}$
$S=(-\infty,2)\cup[-1,1]\cup(2,\infty)$

As an alternative, we have that

for $|x|-2>0$ that is for $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup (2,+\infty)$

$$\implies |x|-1>1>0 \implies\frac {|x|-1}{|x|-2}>0$$

for $|x|-2<0$ we need

$$|x|-1\le0 \iff x\in[-1,1]$$
therefore the solution is their union that is $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup [-1,1] \cup (2,+\infty)$.
